# How can I recreate a blocking process which uses FETCH API_CURSOR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, cursor

My organization has recently had trouble with some SQL Server blocking processes. dbWarden has successfully reported blocking to us, but we often have the blocking SQL text reported as 'FETCH API_CURSOR'.
   So, we're looking to alter the blocking alerts trigger in dbWarden to use sys.dm_exec_cursors and sys.dm_exec_sql_text to retrieve the text in the case where we find 'FETCH API_CURSOR' reported.

Trouble is, I cannot seem to come up with a way to recreate/simulate a blocking situation on our development server that will report as 'FETCH API_CURSOR'. I've started from the VB script [here on SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/01/10/sql-server-what-is-the-query-used-in-sp_cursorfetch-and-fetch-api_cursor/) to recreate the open cursor, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it blocking.

I've seen many methods for recreating blocking transactions (open a transaction in one window, but do not commit/close, then try an update on same table in another), but not that would utilize FETCH API_CURSOR in a way that would allow us to successfully test. I'm somewhat at a loss here.

Has anyone had success in simulating blocking cursors in the past and can offer suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use Profiler tool to capture actual code that creates and fetches cursor. In this case, you'd see exactly what's going on in an application. It is not so difficult to reproduce similar blocking on a development server.

Let's say, one thread fetches rows from a cursor and another thread try to UPDATE same rows. See what's going on under the hood. Reading thread creates cursor to fetch result of SELECT back to an application. This technology is ancient and extremely slow and nowaday only some old (mostly) Java application use cursors for this purpose. Rows get fetched one-by-one, client is handling this process, so it takes time. During this time, reading thread holds shared locks on data it reads. It is by design, SQL Server is locker, it does use locks to function properly. If another thread tries to update a row that has been locked with shared lock, it get blocked. Because updating thread uses shared locks when searching rows for update, and tries to upgrade it to something more serious, but can't. For example, you can't upgrade your shared lock to U lock if another thread owns S lock on the same row. So I'd try to create a cursor, fetch several rows and tried to update in another tab. If you see difficulties, try to increase reading transaction serialization level.

But, seriously, I don't think you have to reproduce this or similar scenario on a development server. Stop use cursors for recordset fetching! Reads will be much faster and blocking issues will be reduced a lot. It's been a while since 1989 when cursors seen their great times. Client DB-access libraries evolved a lot, it is worth trying to pick up fruits of progress. Even in Java, it is a configuration option, use or not use them.

I apologize if cursor does get used on purpose, in this case. It is very unprobably but possible. I haven't seen such 'proper' cursor usage for ages! I'll be delighted to run into one more proper case.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a T-SQL cursor (cursor created within the SQL Query) - it's an [API Server Cursor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187088%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  We are unable to use SQL Profiler on the production server to capture what is causing this blocking because a) it is very infrequent - we've had two incidents over the past two days, and the previous was 3 months ago - Profiler would significantly affect performance; b) profiler does not capture the details of the API cursor (see the link to the SQL Authority article in my question).

Comment: We only need to recreate the API Cursor **with blocking** so that we can test our method to capture the details. Once we've validated that, we can implement the dbWarden change in PRD to capture the cause of the API Cursor the next time it happens.